# Make backticks and links overlap work with GitHub Markdown

Tags: github, markdown, overlap

We are trying to implement an automatic markdown generator for an easily maintainable documentation.

When mentioning a variable's type, we would like to prefix it with `?` when it is nullable, use backticks around it and add a link to its description. For example: `` `?[Article](#article)` ``.

However, the backticks break the link syntax because of the overlap. We use `` `?`[`Article`](#article) `` instead to make the link works but it creates a space between `?` and `Article` as follow: `?``Article`.

Is it possible to make it look like `?Article` with a link on `Article` only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested this out and discovered that there is *no* space between `?` and `Article`. What appears to be a space is simply GitHub's styling of two `<code>` blocks up against each other.

Wrapping the whole thing in backticks won't work because backticks indicate code, and Markdown treats the contents as if they are a code sample where you want to show the source.

The best workaround I can find is to use `<code>` tags directly:

```
<code>?[Article](https://stackoverflow.com/)</code>
```

On both GitHub and Stack Overflow this renders like so:

`?Article`

(I have used a link to Stack Overflow as the link target here simply so we get a rendered link as an example. I expect that `#article` will work equally well in your environment.)

In my opinion this is even a reasonable way of doing what you want. Markdown's backticks compile to `<code>` tags, and [inline HTML code is expressly permitted by Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself. There’s no need to preface it or delimit it to indicate that you’re switching from Markdown to HTML; you just use the tags.

Comment: I did not know it was possible to use inline HTML in Markdown, thank you!